# How to make div transition smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, uikit, css-transitions

Upon clicking on the checkbox I want one element appears smoothly and other disappears smoothly

I have used **UI Kit.**

Here is the code of my attempt:
https://codepen.io/Abdubek/pen/wvwdaoE

```js
UIkit.util.on("#button", 'click', function() {
  UIkit.toggle("#red", {
    animation: "uk-animation-fade"
  }).toggle();
  UIkit.toggle("#blue", {
    animation: "uk-animation-fade"
  }).toggle();
})
```

```css
.red {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
}

.blue {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.1.7/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

<div class="uk-container uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle uk-flex-column">
  <input type="checkbox" id="button" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-margin-bottom" />

  <div id="red" class="red"></div>
  <div id="blue" aria-hidden="true" hidden class="blue"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.2.0/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.2.0/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.2.0/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<div class="uk-container uk-padding uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle uk-flex-column">

<p class="box box-first uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-text-muted uk-flex 
uk-flex-middle uk-flex-center uk-text-lead uk-margin-remove">BOX [ A ]</p>
<p class="box box-second uk-background-primary uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-light uk-flex uk-flex-middle uk-flex-center uk-text-lead uk-margin-remove" hidden>BOX [ B ]</p>
  
  <button
      class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-margin"
      type="button"
      uk-toggle="target: .box; animation: uk-animation-fade; queued: true; duration: 300"
  >Toggle Box</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('#button').change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
   $('#red').addClass('blue');
      }
 
     else {
        $('#red').removeClass('blue');
     }
   });
});
```

```css
#red {
   width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 2s linear;

}

.blue {
   width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue !important;
  transition: all 2s linear;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uk-container uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle uk-flex-column">
  <input type="checkbox" id="button" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-margin-bottom"/>
  <div class="main-container"> 
    <div id="red">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to change the element itself, not add a class

Answer (score 0):

You just need to stack one box on top of the other

```
.uk-container{
  position : relative;
}
.red,.blue{
  position:absolute;
  top:50px

}
```

Comment: the block is just for example, there are many elements and the absolute value will not work

Answer (score 0):

As you used checkbox you need to check checkbox is check or uncheck , I used jquery to solve this,

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){   
   $('#button').change(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
   $('#red').hide();
       $('#blue').show();
      }
 
     else {
        $('#red').show();
        $('#blue').hide();
     }
   });
});
```

```css
.red {
   width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 2s linear;

}

.blue {
   width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: blue;
  transition: all 2s linear;
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uk-container uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-flex-middle uk-flex-column">
  <input type="checkbox" id="button" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-margin-bottom"/>
  <div class="main-container"> 
  <div id="red" class="red">
  </div>
  <div id="blue" aria-hidden="true" hidden class="blue">
    
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I needed a smooth animation when changing a block